# What is the meaning of "que fuñenga"?

Tags: traducción, etimología, vocabulario, expresiones

On Twitter, I came across the expression "que fuñenga". The full tweet is:

> Se dañó la nevera  que fuñenga

With the help of Google Translate, I get that the Twitter user is saying that her fridge stopped working. But when she says "que fuñenga", the translation I am getting on Google Translate is "let it go", which I don't understand...

- What is the meaning of *fuñenga*?
- Is *fuñenga* a verb?
- Has the Twitter user made a typo and meant something else?

All answers are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7/8/21:
I tried to look up this word in a 1960s Spanish-English Dictionary and it was no where to be found. Then I tried a Google search and all I found on Google was the link to the question you asked on this site, and then I tried Google translate. The translation I received from Google translate was the same word: fuñenga (how weird), so I asked your question on another Q&A forum website and the answers I received might be of help to you.

According to the first answerer, this word "fuñenga" is slang, and is unheard of depending on the country you are from, for example if your from Colombia and the person tweeting this is from Chile, then you have never heard of this word because every country has their own colloquial expressions. Of course Chile and Colombia are just examples I don't know where you are from and I don't know where the person tweeting this is from either. The point is Spanish colloquial expressions vary from one Spanish-speaking country to another. The context may give us a clue that the person tweeted: Oh poop! The fridge is broken. The second answerer said that this could have been a typo and the word actually meant to be tweeted was "Fango" which can mean sludge or mud.

When I asked your question on this other forum, part of what I posted got cut off because it was too long, so when the first answerer looked this word up on Twitter, the first answerer found out that the tweet actually read: Se dañó la nevera  que fuñenga instead of que fuñenga Se dañó la nevera. The first answerer then said: "This can suggest a slight change, and I would then translate it as The fridge broke. What a drag!"

so fuñenga probably means drag

If context is all you have, then context is very important in what determines the meaning of fuñenga to a translator and the more context you have the better. If you don't have enough context, then all you can do is assume the meaning and then this word (or any other unheard of word) is better left untouched because if you have to assume the meaning that means there is not enough context to allow the translator to determine the actual meaning, however, I know you provided all the context you could provide.

The first answerer thought this expression "que fuñenga" comes from Cuba, Puerto Rico, or the Dominican Republic because of the way fuñenga is spelled at the end (n-g-a).

The second answerer said "Also possible that it’s not straight Spanish. Some countries in South America, like Uruguay and Paraguay, have a mixture of Spanish, Portuguese, Portuñol and Guarani, (an indigenous language from Paraguay)."

I hope this answer helps.

7/9/21:
In addition to all this:

It should be noted that according to https://www.spanishdict.com/phrases/que the word que without an accent on the e means: *that*. And the word qué with an accent on the e means: *what*

A third answerer noted that on Google translate que fuñenga means: *let it go*. And the third answerer also noted that on Google translate fuñenga means: *fuñenga*. In other words there is no English translation for fuñenga alone.

Now I know why the first answerer thought que fuñenga could be translated to *what a drag*. This is because qué means: *what*. The full tweet says: Se dañó la nevera  que fuñenga. There is no accent on the e in the word que in this tweet. The first answerer thought there was an accent on the e in que and that maybe the person who tweeted this forgot to add this accent.

Now I can see why que fuñenga is translated as *let it go* on Google translate. This is because because the words *it* and *that* are both grammatically used the same way in English. In spanish que means *that*, but Google translate is translating que as *it* when Google translate should be translating que as *that*, so Google translate should have translated que fuñenga as *let that go* instead of *let it go*, but Google translate is just a machine translator, not a human. where did the word *it* come from, when que means *that*? Whoever programmed this machine translator at Google probably thought que could be translated as *it* because since que means *that*, this machine translator can have the word *it* as a translation because *it* and *that* are grammatically used interchangeably in English.

You might want to read about the words *it* and *that* on this site: https://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2014/01/22/it-vs-that-in-grammar-conversation-english-lesson/

I hope this edited answer helps.

7/10/21:
I recently asked on the other Q&A forum website as a separate question if que (without the accent on the e) can ever translate to *it*? or does que only translate to *that*? If Google translate is correct that “que fuñenga” means “let it go,” does “que” translate to “it” or does “que” only translate to “that”? If “que” only translates to “that,” should Google translate have translated “que fuñenga” as “let that go”? and in my separate question I noted the difference between que and qué and then second answerer to my separate question with my note said:

Most of the time, **translations cannot be literal**, that means word by word because you will end up with something crazy. Good translation is about **understanding the expression you want to translate and look for the equivalent in the other language that best fits**, even if it doesn’t match word by word. What really matters is to convey the meaning so that it communicates the same meaning in both languages.

1. **It** does not have a direct equivalent in Spanish all the time. If **it** is used as the **subject** of the sentence, it is not translated: **it rains = llueve**.
2. **It** translates as **la or lo** if it is used as the **object** of the sentence: **I bought it = lo compré**.
3. Yes, both **it and that** can most of the time be used interchangeably in English. (Which has nothing to do with the expression ¡qué fuñenga!).
4. **That** in English can act as a connecting word (it’s a relative pronoun) **The book that you read**. or can act as **it** (object pronoun) **I read it** or **I read that**.
5. **que** without an accent can be translated as **that** or **what** (you are wrong when you say that que w/o an accent only translates as that because it translates to what as well).
6. **que** meaning **that** usually connects two structures (conjunction)—not the case here.
7. **que** without an accent can mean **what** as in **what I like is pizza = lo que me gusta es la pizza**.
8. **qué** with an accent is a question word as in **What do you like? = ¿Qué te gusta?**.
9. **None of the above applies to the expression ¡qué fuñenga!** which is called an **interjection or exclamatory idiom/sentence** (expressions of strong emotion that carry exclamation points).
10. There is a rule for **exclamatory sentences** that requires the use of **qué** with an accent, as in **What a nice surprise! = ¡Qué linda sorpresa!**
11. Therefore, to conclude, **¡qué fuñenga! falls in to point 10, and that is why it carries qué with an accent.**

This is everything the second answerer told me.

Then I asked your question again on a another different Q&A forum website to see if I could get more insight from more people and the first answerer (and maybe the only answerer because this question turned out to be a duplicate in this Q&A forum website in particular) said:

Que *fuñenga* is a very Spanish way to express dissatisfaction when something is wrong or does not work properly, meaning *misfortune, setback, mishap, complication*. Normally people will say “qué jodienda”, but it does not sound nice.“Que *fuñenga*, se me estropeó el televisor! ("What a *setback* my TV is broken).

That is everything this first answerer (and will probably be the only answerer) told me.

I sincerely hope this latest edit clears everything up for you.

---

7/23/21:

https://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/fu%C3%B1enda.php

https://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/fu%C3%B1ir.php

https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fu%C3%B1enda

https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fu%C3%B1enda

Answer (score 5):

In the [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://www.rae.es/) there is only a handful of words that start with **fuñ** and none ot them have an **e** after the **ñ**.  Thus **fuñenga** is not a word recognized by the Real Academia Española.

The [Diccionario de americanismos](https://lema.rae.es/damer/) does not include the word **fuñenga**, but it has the very similar [**fuñenda**](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fu%C3%B1enda):

> I.  1.  f. RD. Fastidio, molestia o disgusto.

and that sense (annoyance) fits well with the user's fridge stopping working.

Therefore my guess is that **fuñenga** is a typo, and it should be **fuñenda**.

Comment: I would just point out that it is not uncommon for colloquial words to have various forms, with the voiced ficatives being the most often swapped. (cf. the informal pronunciation of 'abuelo' in many places as 'agüelo')

Comment: This website: https://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/fu%C3%B1enda.php says that "fuñenda" is a form of the verb "fuñir" and tells you that the definitions of "fuñenda" are calamidad, disgusto, contrariedad, and molestia. You'll see example sentences using "fuñenda." And on the same website look up "fuñir" and the definitions are molestar, fastidiar and more words. This website says "fuñenda" is from the Dominican Republic, but also says that "fuñir" has meanings in Spain, Puerto Rico, Cuba, Venezuela, and Colombia.

Comment: Here is the link for "fuñir": https://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/fu%C3%B1ir.php

Comment: @Edna: **fuñir** no figura en el DLE (https://dle.rae.es/fu%C3%B1ir). Aunque si figura en el Diccinario de americanismos, (https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fuñir) tambien aparece fuñenda (https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fu%C3%B1enda), como ya recojo en la respuesta, con la indicación RD = República Dominicana.

Comment: Thank you for the links.